# XML Schema - Only one of elements can have an attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, schematron

I have a struggle with XSD schema. I want to put a restriction where only one of the element within a node can have the cetrain arttribute and don't affect the other one.

Giving you an example of valid and invalid XML files would be better:

**Valid XML**

The tag `someone` must contain the attriubte `@id`, but the only one of them would be honored to have the `@status` attribute with the `captain` value.

```
<node>
    <someone id="01">Alex</someone>
    <someone id="02">Amanda</someone>
    <someone id="03" status="captain">Bob</someone>
    <someone id="04">Costa</someone>
</node>
```

---

**Invalid XML**

The following ones are invalid. There is no way to have two ones with `@status`.

```
<node>
    <someone id="01" status="captain">Alex</someone>
    <someone id="02">Amanda</someone>
    <someone id="03" status="captain">Bob</someone>
    <someone id="04">Costa</someone>
</node>
```

And also not possible to skip the `@id`.

```
<node>
    <someone status="captain">Alex</someone>
    <someone id="01">Amanda</someone>
    <someone id="02">Costa</someone>
</node>
```

---

**My actual XSD**

I have the following piece of `xsd` file so far, however I have no idea how to apply the restriction described above.

```
<xsd:complexType name="nodeType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="someone" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="idType" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

---

I am thankful for the help. I think the way using [schematron](/questions/tagged/schematron) would do the work better and easier, however I have a really little experience with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done with XSD 1.0. Very easy to do with XSD 1.1 using assertions. Not sure I understand the condition exactly, but it's something

```
<xs:assert test="count(*/@status)=1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have been looking for. Just of being curious: Is there a way to do the same with Schematron?

Comment: Yes, schematron has the same expressive power. But it's a long time since I've used it so I don't remember the syntax.

Comment: Thank you anyway for the kind help :))

Comment: please look at my reply which mentions validating the xml using schematron

Comment: @MichaelKay Can you please help me in finding out java library that supports XSD 1.1 processing? I tried a lot and a lot and finally settled to schematron

Comment: XSD 1.1 is implemented in Altova, Saxon, and Xerces.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the required schematron:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<iso:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
    queryBinding='xslt2' schemaVersion='ISO19757-3'>
    <iso:pattern id="check">
        <iso:rule context="/node/someone">
            <iso:assert test= "count(.[@status='captain']) = 1">
                You cannont have more than one &lt;someone&gt; with status attribute = captain
            </iso:assert>
            <iso:assert test= "boolean(@id)">
                id is required attribute in &lt;someone&gt;.
            </iso:assert>
        </iso:rule>
    </iso:pattern>
</iso:schema>
```

You might want to check [ph-schematron](https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron) library for Java to test it out.

You can find the working code which uses the above schematron and your sample xml [here](https://github.com/sanaulla123/schematron-demo).

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand its logic now :)